# Large SQL dataset query using java

Tags: java, sql, performance, hibernate, sql-server-2008

I have the following configuration:

- SQL Server 2008
- Java as backend technology - Spring + Hibernate

Basically what I want to do is a select with a where clause on a table. The problem is the table has about 700M entries and the query takes a really long time.

Can you please indicate some pointers on where to optimize the query or what sort of techniques are can I use in order to get an improvement in performance?

Thanks.

Comment: Create database indexes according to your access (query) patterns, in general that's all you need. Or does your query read all the 700m of data in one go?

Comment: Is the where clause selecting a small number of those rows, or is the result set also huge? Are there appropriate indexes on the table?

Answer (score 1):

Using indexes is the standard technique used to deal with this problem. As requested, here are some pointers that should get you started:

- http://odetocode.com/articles/70.aspx
- http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/
- http://www.petri.co.il/introduction-to-sql-server-indexes.htm

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I do in this case is isolate whether it is the amount of data I am returning that is the problem or not (an i/o issue). A simple non-scientific way to do this is change your query to just return the count:

```
select count(*) --just return a count, no data!
from MyTable
inner join MyOtherTable on ...
where ...
```

If this runs very quickly, it tells you your indexes are in order (assuming no sub-selects in your `WHERE` clause). If not, then you need to [work on indexes](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2011/index-maintenance-performance/), the `WHERE` clause, or your query construction itself (JOINs being done, etc).

Once that is satisfactory, add back in your `SELECT` clause. If it is slow, you are going to have to look at your data access pattern:

- Can you return fewer columns?
- Can you return fewer rows at once?
- Is there caching you can do in the application layer?
- Is this query a candidate for partitioned/materialized views (if your database supports those)?

Answer (score 1):

I would run Profiler to find the exact query that is being generated. ORMs can create less than optimal queries. Once you know the query, you can run it in SSMS and see the execution plan. This will give you clues as to where you have performance problems.

Several things that can cause performance problems:

- Lack of correct indexing (Foreign keys should be indexed if you have
  joins as well as the criteria in the where clause)
- Lack of sargability in the where clause forcing the query to not use
  existing indexes
- Returning more columns than are needed
- Correlated subqueries and scalar functions that cause
  row-by-agonzing-row operations
- Returning too much data (will anybody really be looking at 1 million
  records returned? You only want to return the amount you show on page
  not the whole possible recordset)
- Locking and blocking

There's more (After all whole very long books are written o nthis subject) but that should be enough to get you started at where to look.

Comment: Query tuning can get complex and intimidating without adequate tools and knowledge. Great answer; the other thing I would note, is that Hibernate wants to generate the queries for you.  If a query needs to be tuned for performance, you need to tell Hibernate to use your specific query.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some indexes for those column you often use to restrict the result. Other thing is the pagination of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the specific DB, I would do the following:

1. run an explain analyze
2. make sure you have an index for the columns that are part of your where clause
3. If indexes are ok, it's very likely that you are fetching a lot of
   records from disk, which is  very slow: if you really cannot refine
   your query so that you fetch fewer records, consider clustering your
   table, to improve disk locality of your records.